# Char array in c & pointer addition

Tags: c

My instructors give me the following function. So don't blame me for ambiguity lol

```
void step_step_step(char *first, char *second, char *third)
{
    if (third[3] == second[2] + 8 && second[2] == first[1] + 8)
        printf("8: Illinois\n");
    else
                printf("8: ERROR\n");
}
```

I try to call the function in the this way:

```
char *p8_1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    char *p8_2 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    char *p8_3 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    p8_1[9] = 'u';
    p8_2[2] = p8_1[9];
    p8_2[10] = p8_1[9];
    p8_3[3] = p8_2[10];
    step_step_step(p8_1, p8_2, p8_3);
```

And it keeps printing error. What am I doing wrong here? I don't understand why that doesn't work when my other solution does:

```
p8_2[2] = p8_1[1] + 8;
p8_3[3] = p8_2[2] + 8;
step_step_step(p8_1, p8_2, p8_3);
```

Comment: Check the precedence of `+` and `&&`

Comment: Your `+` operators are adding characters, not pointers, so there's no "pointer addition" here.  Instead you're comparing `'u'` to `'u' + 8` and getting non-equal (not suprisingly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You believe the `if` condition should pass, since all the elements you are intending to check is initialized to `'u'`. In your code, this is true for `p8_3[3]`, `p8_2[10]`, `p8_2[2]`, and `p8_1[9]`. Then, there is the call:

```
step_step_step(p8_1, p8_2, p8_3);
```

As `third` takes the `p8_3` value, indexing its 3<sup>rd</sup> element is fine, and it has value `'u'`. However, `second[2]` has the value `'u'`, and then 8 is added to it before the `==` comparison. This results in the `==` to result in a false evaluation. The `&&` is short-circuited, and the `else` case of the `if` is taken.

If short-circuiting had not taken place, the right side expression of the `&&` would compare `second[2]` with `first[1] + 8`. As `first[1]` is uninitialized, this would have resulted in undefined behavior.

---

The indexing operator `ptr[index]` behaves like `*(ptr + index)`. So, the expression:

```
second[2] + 8
```

translates into:

```
*(second + 2) + 8
```

which is definitely **NOT** the same as `*(second + 2 + 8)`.

Comment: How can you even figure out what he's trying to do? :) I'm trying really hard and failing.

Comment: this ones not clear - why wouldnt he say second[10]; maybe he means 'the ascii char 8 steps higher'; although his test doesnt set it up that way

Comment: I am inferring the intended outcome by how he initialized the input.

Comment: Again, my instructors wrote the function. I took it as the the third char arrays index [3] should hold the same character as the second char arrays index [10].. since it's [2] + 8. And the second char arrays index [2] should store the same character as the first char arrays index [9]. since it's [1] + 8

Comment: The `[]` operator does not distribute over `+`.

Comment: so second[10] = 'u' is equivalent to *(second + 2 + 8) = 'u'. Which is not equivalent to second[2]+8 = 'u'? What does does the location (second + 2) + 8 refer to?

Comment: And written as is, what does the function ask for as to satisfy the if condition? in plain english

Comment: `(second + 2) + 8` equals `(second + 2 + 8)` because of math, but it is missing the dereference operator implied in `[]`. So `*(second + 2) + 8` is equal to whatever value is `second[2]`, and then you add `8` to that.

Answer (score 5):

Possible operator precedence bug:

Change to:
`if ((third[3] == second[2] + 8) && (second[2] == first[1] + 8))`

[The wiki article on 'Order of operations'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) tells more about the evaluation precedence.

If you can't explain to someone in the blink of an eye, in which order some expression will be evaluated - you should use enough parentheses that it won't matter (because no order precedence to care of) or that it's instantly obvious how the clauses are separated.

**EDIT:**

A closer look makes me realize something fishy is going on. You're not incrementing any pointers. If you were, you would do something like `if ((third[3] == second[2 + 8]) && (second[2] == first[1 + 8]))`

Comment: There is no operator precedence issue *per se*, although parentheses may add clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like p8_1[1] has not been initialized. In your "working" example you assign the random value that's in p8_1[1] to p8_2[2], resulting in their equality. If you're trying to do pointer addition, you need to use a different syntax:

```
(pointer + (8*sizeof(char))[<index>]
```